# Allow SWF Tools to grant access to supported private files

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, drupal, ftp

I am currently trying to replace a slideshow on a website.  I have the slideshow in a swf file and ready to upload.  I am limited to ftp access and the websites drupal administration site.  The person that orginally designed and maintained the website is no longer in business and unreachable.  I have uploaded the swf via ftp and named it the same name as the old slideshow.  Nothing changed.  I found an option on our website administration area that says Allow SWF Tools to grant access to supported private files.  I have not tried this yet because I am unsure of the outcome and I do not need to cause any sort of damage to our live website being that we do not currently have anyone to contact to resolve the issue.  If I select this option and limiting the file extension down to just swf could this cause any sort of problems with the actual website?  Also is this even a possible solution to my problem of the website not showing the updated file.  Also, I am placing the file in the correct directory that the html is referencing and the media directory listed on drupal.  There are other swf files inside of this directory too for other pages of the website.

These are what the options look like:

Allow SWF Tools to grant access to supported private files 
If using a private file system then SWF Tools is unable to access files that are not uploaded via a file module that supports a private file system. For example, SWF Tools will be unable to access files that were manually uploaded via FTP. Enabling this setting will allow SWF Tools to grant access to files with extensions defined by the next setting. Note - if another module denies access then access to the file will not be granted. SWF Tools itself does not deny access to any file. SWF Tools always allows access to files in the playlists directory. 
Extensions that SWF Tools will allow access to:

![Under a private file system SWF Tools will grant access to files with extensions in this list. Separate extensions with a space and do not include the leading dot. Although any extension can be added to this list, only swf flv xml mp3 jpg jpeg and png will return the correct headers.][1]

Allow SWF Tools to grant access to supported private files 
If using a private file system then SWF Tools is unable to access files that are not uploaded via a file module that supports a private file system. For example, SWF Tools will be unable to access files that were manually uploaded via FTP. Enabling this setting will allow SWF Tools to grant access to files with extensions defined by the next setting. Note - if another module denies access then access to the file will not be granted. SWF Tools itself does not deny access to any file. SWF Tools always allows access to files in the playlists directory. 
Extensions that SWF Tools will allow access to:

Extensions that SWF Tools will allow access to:

Comment: its just cached in your browser, clear your cache and restart your browser.

Comment: I have tried several different computers across several different locations, the change I made did not update.